# How to paginate awesome_print results inside pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console, pry

I'm using `awesome_print` gem to display output from `pry` to look pretty. Since,  `awesome_print` uses line breaks, long outputs like `ap html.chapters.order("position ASC")`  only shows the end part of the output, How Do I paginate the result to look like its, piped to `less` or `more`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to the `.pryrc`:

```
begin
  require 'awesome_print' 
  Pry.config.print = proc { |output, value| Pry::Helpers::BaseHelpers.stagger_output("=> #{value.ai}", output) }
rescue LoadError => err
  puts "no awesome_print :("
end
```

https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ#wiki-awesome_print

And in case you are unfamiliar with `.pryrc`:

> When pry starts, it checks for a .pryrc file in your home
>   directory(~/.pryrc) and also for a per-project .pryrc in the current
>   directory(./.pryrc). Both files are used if they exist, with the file
>   from your home directory being loaded first.

https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Pry-rc